# How are quaternions a finite set?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quaternions

I'm having trouble understanding how Quaternions are a finite set when you can express a quaternion as Q = a + ib + jc+ kd, because a, b, c, d are $\in$ of $\Re$ would this not mean that the set is infinite?

Comment: What makes you think they are finite?

Comment: Yes, the set of quaternions is infinite. But the quaternions has finite *dimension* as a vector space over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you mean "Quaternion Groups" which for your case has order 8, it is of course finite but it is not defined as you did.

Comment: What is the difference the set of quaternions being infinite and quaternions having a finite dimension as a vector space over R?

Comment: The OP probably is referring to the **quaternion group**, according to his tagging. Google this and you shall see the huge difference between this and the Hamilton Quaternions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quaternions, as a set, is infinite.

However, the quaternions, seen as a vector space over the reals, has finite *dimension*, e.g. the set $\{1,i,j,k\}$ form a basis, so the dimension is 4. This means that any quaternion $x$ can be written uniquely on the form:
$$x = \alpha_11 + \alpha_2i + \alpha_3j + \alpha_4k$$
for $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4 \in \mathbb R$.

The *quaternion group*
$$Q = \langle -1, i, j, k \mid (-1)^2 = 1, i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1 \rangle$$
is a group of finite order, the order being 8.

Comment: So quaternions and the quaternion group are completely different things?

Comment: Yes, they are different things. They are however related: the quaternion group embodies the basic multiplicative structure of the quaternions.

Comment: And that the quaternions form a 4-dimensional vector space over the reals gives information about the *additive* structure of the quaternions.

Answer (score 3):

The set of all quaternions is not finite. However, the basis quaternions (1,i,j,k) generate a finite group under quaternionic multiplication.

Comment: Righto. Edited answer to reflect this